# java ORM for a read only DB

Tags: java, database, forms, readonly

I know hibernate but I wonder if there would be a lighter ORM engine for a **read only** database. I mean, I don't need some transactional queries or to update some records. On the other side, I need to handle some large list of records:

```
List<MyRecord> list= object.getMyRecords(); // list.size() > 1E7
```

Does such engine exist ?
Many thanks,

Pierre

Comment: What's wrong with hibernate, what limit did u reach to start searching another ORM?

Comment: I've nothing vs Hibernate, but I wonder if another ORM exists. I find hibernate to takes a long time to setup with many dependecies, transactions are useless (in my case) and I'm afraid it won't support a large number of items in my lists.

Comment: For few classes to map and read-only i would go with a good connection pool library (c3p0) and JDBC as "light engine".

Comment: Are these large collections of objects intended to be accessed through natural keys, or only iterated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out **[JIRM](https://github.com/agentgt/jirm)** (yes, that is a shameless plug) which is an ORM focused on using immutable objects.

It sits right on top of Spring JDBC so, if you're using Spring, it's very low risk to try it.

It also has really nice [SQL placeholder templates](https://github.com/agentgt/jirm/tree/master/jirm-core#sql-placeholder-parser) that do not require Spring.

Another project you should checkout is [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider [MyBatis](http://mybatis.org/) (IBatis 3) ORM library. It fits the requirements from light-weight work to some heavy batch executions. So it'll fit your current needs very well and won't through you out of luck when you require some heavy-lifting work from your underlying ORM library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a lightweight ORM framework, look no further than [OrmLite](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to avoid most of the overhead of setting up more complicated ORM frameworks like Hibernate. The downside to this framework is that it does not support standard JPA annotations so it would not be easy to swap this ORM out for a different one later on.

I would suggest trying out [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) which is a JPA standard compliant ORM framework maintained by the Apache foundation. It is one of Hibernate major competitors. It does have a bit more overhead to setup but it has the advantage of allowing you to swap it out in the future for a different JPA compliant framework (like Hibernate) if it no longer suits your needs.

Both of these frameworks are Open Source as well which is always a good reason for using them.

Comment: Actually ORMLite does support a subset of JPA annotations but not the full complement.

Answer (score 1):

I searched lite ORM too for one project about a year ago. And tried a couple of them. I was a bit unsatisfied with all solutions because each of them was trying to move in certain direction.

Hibernate is a huge and it can be a source of extra troubles when you want just simple solution. Currently I am working on the one nice project it uses little custom layer over tables.

You can probably try to implement a little layer over your database with JDBC using some patterns like Active Record or Table Gateway, etc.

Any ORM solution just tries to be very unified and ads extra tails to your project. But you can create your own custom layer-less solution - this will especially work fine if you database have predefined set of tables and doesn't change it's structure too often.

Comment: @Martin - didn't see it before - the access API looks nice - very similar to active record. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If you are interested, please give it a try and let us know your feedback. What is your database engine of choice?

Comment: @Martin I will take it in mind on any new project. I am not bound to any specific db, but mysql is one of the most popular right now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ebeans](http://www.avaje.org/) which is a light ORM tool:

- Reuses JPA Annotations (@Entity, @OneToMany ...) for mapping.
- Uses a *Session Less* architecture (i.e. has a simpler API than JPA).
- Supports immutable Value Object.
- Allows to use [ORM or Relational features](http://www.avaje.org/design.html#eb)
- Claims to provide good [large query](http://www.avaje.org/jpaapi.html#largequery) support

Worth the look IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's SimpleJDBCTemplate combined with result mappers worked marvels for me in read only scenarios, you don't get the unneeded overhead of hibernate, all your pseudo-ORM mapping is bundled together, it is a true win for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a lightweight ORM I would recommend [jORM](https://github.com/jajja/jorm). Note that my answer is biased, since I'm one of the contributors to the project.

The main reasons why we decided to write a lightweight alternative are (the need for):

- Hazzlefree configuration
- Clear transaction definitions
- Memory management and speed
- Simple code generation
- Hand tuned SQL

In short; rapid development.

**Example configuration**

```
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/moria");
dataSource.setUsername("gandalf");
dataSource.setPassword("mellon");

Database.configure("moria", dataSource); // now there's a named database
```

**Example record**

```
@Jorm(database="moria", table="goblins", id="id")
public class Goblin extends Record {  
    public Integer getId() {
        return get("id", Integer.class);
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        set("id", id);
    }
    public Integer getTribeId() {
        return get("tribe_id", Integer.class);
    }
    public void setTribeId(Integer id) {
        set("tribe_id", id);
    }
    public Tribe getTribe() {
        return get("tribe_id", Tribe.class);
    }
    public void setTribe(Tribe tribe) {
        set("tribe_id", tribe);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return get("name", String.class);
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        set("name", name);
    }
}
```

**Example mapped queries**

```
Goblin goblin = Record.findById(Goblin.class 42);

List<Goblin> goblins = Record.findAll(Goblin.class);Goblin bolg = Record.find(Goblin.class, new Column("name", "Bolg"));
```

**Example custom queries**

```
Tribe tribe = new Tribe();
tribe.setId(1);
String name = "Azog";

Goblin azog = Record.select(
    Goblin.class,
    "SELECT * FROM goblins WHERE name = #1# AND tribe_id = #2:id#",
    name, // #1#
    tribe // #2#
);

Goblin bolg = Record.find(Goblin.class, "SELECT * FROM goblins WHERE name = #1#", "Bolg");
```